# Only show commands that user can execute in custom help message

Tags: discord.py

I have my custom help format in which i want to only show command that the user requesting help can execute. Meaning that a normal user will not see commands like kick and help, however I don't know how to accomplish this.

I am getting a list of commands each cog has using

> cog.commands().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching and just trying out whatever functions i could on the doc, this is the solution i have come to.

```py
def can_run(cmd, ctx):
    """Our own version of checking if command can be run"""
    if not cmd.checks:
        return True
    else:
        for check in cmd.checks:
            try:
                if check(ctx):
                    return True
            except:
                return False
        return False
```

Where cmd is the command that need to be tested and ctx is the context. This will return true if the user can execute the command.

Feel free to improve on it.